# Lync issue: There was a p verifying the certificate from the server

Tags: lync

all

This problem cames out when I try to use another pc to login lync for user.
Then the message " There was a problem verifying the certificate from the server." appears.

So, do anyone have a clue to solve this, or could I export the cert from user's computer then import it into this one?

Luke